# Index Out Of Range Bucket Sort

Tags: c#, sorting

So I wrote bucket sort implementation (I use `rnd.NextDouble()` to fill my array, so all the elements are in the range between 0 and 1). And I have number of experiments (10 experiments for each array size) and different array sizes (I start with 1000 and then +1000, etc. till 300.000). And sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it gives me OutOfRange exception:

```
public static void BucketSortImplement(ref int countOfElements, ref float[] array)
{
    List<float>[] buckets = new List<float>[countOfElements];

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = new List<float>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
    {
        float indexOfElement = array[i] * countOfElements;
        buckets[(int)indexOfElement].Add(array[i]);       // right here
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < buckets[i].Count; j++)
        {
            float keyElement = buckets[i][j];
            int k = j - 1;

            while (k >= 0 && buckets[i][k] > keyElement)
            {
                buckets[i][k + 1] = buckets[i][k];
                k -= 1;
            }

            buckets[i][k + 1] = keyElement;
        }
    }

    int arrayIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < buckets[i].Count; j++)
        {
            array[arrayIndex++] = buckets[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused, because the algorithm itself looks fine, that is I have to calculate `array[i] * countOfElements` to get the index where I can put my element. Could you please direct me?

Answer (score 2):

If you array contain value '1' it will lead to OutOfRange, because if you have a size of the list equal to 3 (for example) then valid indexes will be in the range [0, 2].

Comment: NextDouble() returns a random floating-point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and LESS than 1.0.

Comment: Maximum value of the NextDouble is 0.99999999999999978. If you cast it to float you will get 1.0.

Comment: Darn that's interesting, I learnt something else today.

Comment: @SergeyMiryanov Wow thank you so much! This has solved my problem)